# What could be incorrect in my code that I get this: PhoneBook.exe has triggered a breakpoint. occurred

Tags: c++, pointers, exception

I would like to create a simple phone book console application in c++. I can't use stl containers (vector, list,...) so I have to write everything.
Here is the Git repo: [PhoneBook](https://github.com/dinci11/PhoneBook.git)

Person.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

char* stringcpy(char* destination, const char* source)
{
    for (int i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = source[i];
        destination[i + 1] = '\0';
    }
    return destination;
}

Person::Person()
{
    firstName = nullptr;
    lastName = nullptr;
    nickName = nullptr;
    address = nullptr;
    workPhone = nullptr;
    privatePhone = nullptr;
}

Person::Person(const char* pFirstName, const char* pLastName, const char* pNickName, const char* pAddress, const char* pWorkPhone, const char* pPrivatePhone)
{
    firstName = new char[strlen(pFirstName) + 1];
    lastName = new char[strlen(pLastName) + 1];
    nickName = new char[strlen(pNickName) + 1];
    address = new char[strlen(pAddress) + 1];
    workPhone = new char[strlen(pWorkPhone) + 1];
    privatePhone = new char[strlen(pPrivatePhone) + 1];

    stringcpy(firstName, pFirstName);
    stringcpy(lastName, pLastName);
    stringcpy(nickName, pNickName);
    stringcpy(address, pAddress);
    stringcpy(workPhone, pWorkPhone);
    stringcpy(privatePhone, pPrivatePhone);


}

Person::Person(Person & p)
{
    delete[] firstName;
    delete[] lastName;
    delete[] nickName;
    delete[] address;
    delete[] workPhone;
    delete[] privatePhone;

    firstName = new char[strlen(p.firstName) + 1];
    lastName = new char[strlen(p.lastName) + 1];
    nickName = new char[strlen(p.nickName) + 1];
    address = new char[strlen(p.address) + 1];
    workPhone = new char[strlen(p.workPhone) + 1];
    privatePhone = new char[strlen(p.privatePhone) + 1];

    stringcpy(firstName, p.firstName);
    stringcpy(lastName, p.lastName);
    stringcpy(nickName, p.nickName);
    stringcpy(address, p.address);
    stringcpy(workPhone, p.workPhone);
    stringcpy(privatePhone, p.privatePhone);
}


Person::~Person()
{
    delete[] firstName;
    delete[] lastName;
    delete[] nickName;
    delete[] address;
    delete[] workPhone;
    delete[] privatePhone;
}

Person& Person::operator=(Person p)
{
    if (this != &p) {
        delete[] firstName;
        delete[] lastName;
        delete[] nickName;
        delete[] address;
        delete[] workPhone;
        delete[] privatePhone;

        firstName = new char[strlen(p.firstName) + 1];
        lastName = new char[strlen(p.lastName) + 1];
        nickName = new char[strlen(p.nickName) + 1];
        address = new char[strlen(p.address) + 1];
        workPhone = new char[strlen(p.workPhone) + 1];
        privatePhone = new char[strlen(p.privatePhone) + 1];

        stringcpy(firstName, p.firstName);
        stringcpy(lastName, p.lastName);
        stringcpy(nickName, p.nickName);
        stringcpy(address, p.address);
        stringcpy(workPhone, p.workPhone);
        stringcpy(privatePhone, p.privatePhone);
    }
    return *this;
}

bool Person::operator==(Person & p)
{
    if (strcmp(firstName, p.firstName) == 0 && strcmp(lastName, p.lastName) == 0 && strcmp(nickName, p.nickName) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

PhoneBook.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "PhoneBook.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


PhoneBook::PhoneBook(string pbFileName, int pbSize)
{
    fileName = pbFileName;
    contacts = new Person[size];
    size = pbSize;
    currentSize = 0;
}


PhoneBook::~PhoneBook()
{
    delete[] contacts;
}

void PhoneBook::addPerson(Person p)
{
    if (currentSize < size)
    {
        contacts[currentSize] = p;
        currentSize++;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The phonebook is full!\n";
    }



}

void PhoneBook::removePerson(Person p)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
    {
        if (contacts[i] == p) {
            for (size_t j = i; j < currentSize; j++)
            {
                if (j == size - 1) {

                }
                else
                {
                    contacts[j] = contacts[j + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    currentSize--;
}

void PhoneBook::savePhoneBook()
{

}

void PhoneBook::loadPhoneBook()
{
}

void PhoneBook::printPhoneBook()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < currentSize - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << this->contacts[i].firstName;
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
// PhoneBook.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"
#include "PhoneBook.h"

int main()
{
    PhoneBook pb = PhoneBook("MyPhoneBook", 10);

    Person p1("FirstName1", "LastName1", "nick1", "Addr1", "+123456789", "06123456789");
    pb.addPerson(p1);
    Person p2("FirstName2", "LastName2", "nick2", "Addr2", "+123456789", "06123456789");
    pb.addPerson(p2);
    Person p3("FirstName3", "LastName3", "nick3", "Addr3", "+123456789", "06123456789");
    pb.addPerson(p3);
    Person p4("FirstName4", "LastName4", "nick4", "Addr4", "+123456789", "06123456789");
    pb.addPerson(p4);

    pb.printPhoneBook();

}
```

When I want to run my simple main function than I get the following error [At this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVR9H.png):

> PhoneBook.exe has triggered a breakpoint. occurred

Thanks for any andvice!

Comment: Post a [mcve] that reproduces your problem as required here please. As my advice run your code in the debugger and step through line by line, to see where the problem occurs.

Comment: Post the code here, not links to it. Judging from the error this means that you have some incorrect memory allocation/deallocation issue.

Comment: Check your copy constructors and assignment operators. Are you sure that you're doing "deep" copies?

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text and not character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow.  Functions that operate on character arrays, that are not terminated by '\0', can wreak havoc with a system.